# Grabbing data from same domain and showing it jquery

Tags: jquery

Okay I know this has been done, just don't know how to do it.
I need to grab the container #main from www.com.com/home and display it on www.com.com/otherpage into the container #maindupe

Comment: read about [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like in `$('#maindupe').load('home #main')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.load()`

`$("#maindupe").load("/home #main");`

http://api.jquery.com/load/